# is there a rust equivalent functionality for creating server just like in nodejs?

Tags: rust, tcp

nodejs

```
const server = createServer(socket => {
  socket.on("data", (data) => {
  });
  socket.on("close", () => log("closed"));
});
server.on("error", err => { throw err; });
server.on("close", () => log("shutdown"));
```

I've attempted using TCPlistener in rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html

but it doesn't seem to have all the feature i need, and i dont think the connection is persistent, i can't get a handshake packet from my client side, does TcpListener in rust automatically close the connection, is there a persistent TCP facility in rust that i dont know of?

Comment: Check out the example here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html#reading-the-request.

Comment: We would be better equipped to help you if your question was more specific. What features are you missing? What code are you trying that closes the listener for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a generic TCP server, I'd suggest using Tokio. There are some examples and a lot of documentation available.

https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/examples/echo.rs

Comment: that looks promising , thanks